# " Google API message " : " This API does not support parsing form-encoded input. "

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-tasks-api

I have written the following javascript to create a tasklist in google:

```javascript
postData = {'title':'Netsuite List'};
access_token = 'xxxx';

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists';

headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json';
headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
headers['Content-length'] = 25; 
response = $$.requestURL(url, postData, headers, 'POST');
```

The response says:

```javascript
{ "error": 
{ "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "parseError", "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input." } ], "code": 400, "message": "This API does not support parsing form-encoded input." } 
}
```

What could be the possible error ?

Answer (score 2):

not working

```
contentType: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
```

try with this

```
var headers = { };

headers["Content-Type"] ="application/json ; charset=UTF-8"; 
//remove to parsing form-encoded input error

data:JSON.stringify( model),
//this use for remove to parse error
```

Example:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'Post',
    url: postUrl,
    headers: headers,
    dataType: 'json',//not required in some case
    data:JSON.stringify( model),                
    success: function (data, sts) {
        alert('success');
    },
    error: function (err, sts) {
        var msg;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You sent data like:

```
title=Netsuite%20List
```

But Google API waits for [JSON](http://www.json.org/):

```
{ "title": "Netsuite List" }
```

Try to provide [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) output to the `requestURL` method:

```
postData = JSON.stringify({'title':'Netsuite List'});          // <-- Added JSON.stringify
access_token = 'xxxx';

url = 'https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists';

headers['Content-type'] = 'application/json';
headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + access_token;
headers['Content-length'] = 25; 
response = $$.requestURL(url, postData, headers, 'POST');
```

Also, it's better to get around documentation or source of `$$` object you use and check how it can support sending JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ /* your object */ }),
    dataType: "json",
    beforeSend: (xhr) => {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    },
    //...
```

or :

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "https://www.googleapis.com/tasks/v1/users/@me/lists",
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({ /* your object */ }),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    //...
```